# jaspersoft studio hangs by Searching Data Adapters in project

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio, jasper-plugin

I have installed tibco jaspersoft Studio last version and wanted to edit some jasper files. I have imported the project from git and everytime when I open the project it loads for ever and hangs by **searching Data Adapters** see screenshot: 
[image]

It takes resources and time. Any Idea how to solve this problems?

p.s.: I have also tried pluging for eclipse and got the same problem

Comment: Check the log to get more information about the problem https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/finding-jaspersoft-studio-error-log

Comment: @PetterFriberg it's seems well known problem, issue [#10746](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/10746). Maybe you know a wokraround for this?

Comment: @SergeyBespalov yeah probably an issue with how they use the eclipse plattform, I however have never encountered this (so I can't repro), maybe try with other versions of Studio and most of all check the logs... if we had some log statements maybe someone could figure out the problem and with that the solution

Comment: @PetterFriberg thanks for response. logs that I had was provided at the issue comments [link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/10746#comment-865531)